# Mysql - Sum by other column value

Tags: mysql

Here's the problem. I have a long but not very complex query:

```
SUM(x.value)
FROM valuetable AS x
LEFT JOIN jointable_1 AS y
LEFT JOIN jointable_2 AS z
etc
...
GROUP BY y.id, z.id
```

There are n amount of left joins, and I need to keep it this way, for a new left join must be available any time. I obviously get n value dublicates into SUM, since jointables can have multiple results, and I can not break any of them into subquery for flexible WHERE reasons. I need only one x.value per x.id into SUM, thats also obvious.

-I cannot add x.id to GROUP BY, since I so need one row to have sum per y.id.

-I cannot use the calculation:

```
SUM(x.value)*COUNT(DISTINCT x.id)/COUNT(*)
```

since there can be any number of x.values in sum, as different x.id-s have different amount of joins.

-I cannot go for DISTINCT x.value, since any x.id can have any x.value and they can contain same value.

-I don't know how to create a subquery for sum, since I cannot use the aggregated value (for example GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT x.id)) in subquery, or can I?

Anyways, thats it. I know I can rearrange the query(subqueries instead of joins, different from), but I want to leave it as the last resort. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Using subqueries instead of joins is how I would generally approach this problem.  What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The query is part of a complex setup, which gets a lot of search parameters and other data traveling between queries. I simply try to avoid tailoring data for just one query.

Comment: Well, sometimes needs must.

Comment: defining that is my goal here...

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you. What are the `ON` clauses in your `LEFT JOIN` operations? Can you show some of your table definitions? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, @O.Jones . I am raising a theoretical question here, my left joins are irrelevant in this context. Point, as I tried to say already, is that I am able create subqueries to replace joins that produce more than one result, but I need to know if there is a way to reduce sum while the circumstances are those (no grouping, undefinable count). I don't feel too confident in sql and I thought I might have overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, there's no general way to do what you want without subqueries (or maybe views).

A bit of jargon:  "Cardinality". For our purpose it's the number of rows in a table or a result set. (For our purpose a result set is a kind of virtual table.)

For aggregate functions like `SUM(col)` and `COUNT(*)` to give good results, we must attend to the cardinality of the table being summarized. This kind of thing

```
  SELECT DATE(sale_time) sale_date, 
         store_id,
         SUM(sale_amount) total_sales
    FROM sale
   GROUP BY DATE(sale_time), store_id
```

summarizes the same cardinality of result table as the underlying table, so it generates useful results.

But, if we do this

```
  SELECT DATE(sale.sale_time) sale_date, 
         sale.store_id,
         SUM(sale.sale_amount) total_sales,
         COUNT(promo.promo_id) promos
    FROM sale
    LEFT JOIN promo ON sale.store_id = promo.store_id 
                   AND DATE(sale.sale_time) = promo.promo_date
   GROUP BY DATE(sale.sale_time), sale.store_id
```

we wreck the cardinality of the summarized result set. This will never work unless we know for sure that each store had either zero or one promo records for each given day.  Why not? The LEFT JOIN operation affects the cardinality of the virtual table being summarized. That means some sale_amount values my show up in the SUM more than once, and therefore the SUM won't be correct, or trustworthy.

How can you prevent LEFT JOIN operations from messing up your cardinality?  Make sure your LEFT JOIN's `ON` clause matches each row on the right to exactly zero rows, or exactly one row, on the left. That is, make sure you (virtual) tables on either side of the JOIN have appropriate cardinality.

(In entity-relationship jargon, your SUM fails because you join two entities with a one-to-many relationship before you do the sum.)

The theoretically cleanest way to do it is to perform both aggregate operations before the join. This joins two virtual tables in a way that the LEFT JOIN is either one-to-none or one-to-one

```
  SELECT sales.sale_date, 
         sales.store_id,
         sales.total_sales,
         promos.promo_count
    FROM (
            SELECT DATE(sale_time) sale_date, 
                   store_id,
                   SUM(sale_amount) total_sales
              FROM sale
          GROUP BY DATE(sale_time), sale_store
         ) sales
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT store_id,
                   promo_date
                   COUNT(*) promo_count
              FROM promo
             GROUP BY store_id, promo_date 
         ) promos ON sales.store_id = promos.store_id
                 AND sales.sale_date = promo.promo_date
```

Although this SQL is complex, most servers handle this kind of pattern efficiently.

**Troubleshooting tip**:  If you see   *SUM() ... FROM ... JOIN ... GROUP BY*  all at the same level of a query, you may have cardinality problems.

Comment: Thank you. I feel a lot wiser now. And a new word into my sql vocabulary.
I suspected that logically from the start, but I needed to be sure.

Comment: Just for my further knowledge - I know that having a query in a loop is very bad practice, but what would be better performance-wise, if you always have controlled amount of rows to return -> to have 5+ subqueries for one-to-many joins or just extract the x.id-s and perform a simple ```SELECT value FROM xxx WHERE id IN()``` in a loop for result rows?

Comment: Lots of queries in a loop, where a single query could get the same information, is indeed a time-waster both for server and for your program.  `SELECT value FROM xxx WHERE xxx,id IN (some complex query yielding id values)` is common, and generally efficient. Subqueries generally aren't as bad as your intuition might tell you. Query optimizers are very good these days: attempts to outsmart them are usually a waste of programmer time.